# why distinct can't save changes in value

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have this code

```
trees = AssessmentTaskForm.objects.distinct('tree')
print(trees.count()) # output is 1

trees = trees.distinct('tree_status__name_en')
print(trees.count()) #output is 3
```

and the output are

###### 1 in 1st print

###### 3 in 2nd print

my need is :
i want to use first filtring query and use it as input in 2nd query

Answer (score 0):

[`distinct`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct) is not a filter query, it just returns unique values of a particular field. You can not use it as a filter query directly in another queryset. But, I assume you are looking for [Group By](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#values), because probably what you want is get unique trees and get tree counts for those trees, Hence you can try like this:

```
AssessmentTaskForm.objects.values('tree').annotate(tree_status_count=Count('tree_status__name_en').values('tree', 'tree_status_count')
```